# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable selenium -

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, pageobjects

Here is a small test carried out with selenium in python:

```
 locators = {
        "entreprise_selection": ("ID", 'uidropdownCompanies'),
        "entreprise_load": ("XPATH", "//a[@id='company_98']/div/span"),
        "filter": ("XPATH", '//*[@id="filter"]')


        }

    def load(self, name):
        self.entreprise_selection.click_button()
        self.filter.set_text(name)
        self.entreprise_load.click()
```

And to call test:

`entreprisePage.load(input.name_entreprise)`

There's no problem, everything works fine!

Now I have a problem when I try to have a dynamic xpath:

instead of having  `"//a[@id='company_98']/div/span"`  I am trying to pass the id.

At the test level I add a new parameter (the integer type id that I have to convert to a string to be able to concatenate the xpath):

`entreprisePage.load(input.name_entreprise, input.id_entreprise)`

At the class level I no longer use a locator for the click:

```
 locators = {
        "entreprise_selection": ("ID", 'uidropdownCompanies'),
        "filter": ("XPATH", '//*[@id="filter"]')


        }

    def load(self, name, id_entreprise):
        self.entreprise_selection.click_button()
        self.filter.set_text(name)

        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//a[@id='company_" + str(id_entreprise) + "']/div/span")).click()
```

When running the test I got the following error message:

`FAILED tests/web_tests/test_login.py::TestLogin::test_login[input0] - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

thanks for your help

I've tried to send directly parameters in string format , same  problem :

`entreprisePage.load(input.name_entreprise, "98")`

```
   locators = {
        "entreprise_selection": ("ID", 'uidropdownCompanies'),
        "filter": ("XPATH", '//*[@id="filter"]')


        }

    def load(self, name, id_entreprise):
        self.entreprise_selection.click_button()
        self.filter.set_text(name)

        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//a[@id='company_" + id_entreprise + "']/div/span")).click()
```

`FAILED tests/web_tests/test_login.py::TestLogin::test_login[input0] - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Please provide more code, but it looks like you named a variable in a test suite in such a way that it follows test case naming convention, thus test environment tries to run it as a TC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got an error, because syntax of `find_element` is not correct.

`By.XPATH` is a variable, not a function and you try to call it as a function.

This is correct syntax:

```python
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='company_" + id_entreprise + "']/div/span").click()
```